# Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 not working with Android SDK

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-3-10.1

I can not get Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 to be seen in Eclipse Android SDK. I believe the problem is related to the usb device driver.

I loaded Samsung Kies and it sees the device fine, just not Eclipse.

Comment: Does the phone say 'USB debugging' when you plug it in? Have you tried changing the mode from, for example, camera to MTP (or vice-bersa)? Does running 'adb devices' show the device? Have you got the latest drivers? What version of the operating system are you on? Have you updated the Android SDK and the Eclipse plugin?

Comment: Kies includes the USB drivers for the device. Try running Eclipse as Administrator if you are using Windows. And all the advice above, do all that. We need more information really.